# Seleccionar una clase de dos en un div

Tags: javascript, css, selectores

Estoy tratando separando un arreglo de `div`, por ejemplo:

```
[div.clase1, div.clase1.clase2, div.clase1]
```

Quiero que quede así:

```
array1 = [div.clase1, div.clase1]
array2 = [div.clase1.clase2]
```

Quiero en un arreglo aparte poder guardar los elementos que contengan solo la clase1 y clase2, pero en otro arreglo, quiero poder guardar solo los que tienen clase1.

Mi código es:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clase1.clase2') // para las dos clases

document.querySelectorAll('.clase1') // para la clase1,
```

Cuando hago el segundo selector me trae todos los div, y solo necesito que tengan la clase1. **¿Alguien puede ayudarme?**

Comment: Hola nayeli, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Ésta es una primera pregunta interesante. No te olvides de completar el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y así ganarás tu primera medalla). Saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El selector que toma los elementos con ambas clase ya lo tiene y es correcto:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clase1.clase2')
```

El problema con el otro selector es que trae elementos que además de la clase1 tienen también la clase2. Para evitarlo puedes usar [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:not()) que sirva para restringir el alcance y que no se seleccionen los elementos que cumplan con la condición especificada. Así puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.clase1:not(.clase2)')
```

que seleccionará los elementos con clase1 que no son clase2.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
const class1sin2 = document.querySelectorAll(".class1:not(.class2)");
const class1con2 = document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2");

console.log(class1sin2);
console.log(class1con2);
```

```html
<div class="class1">A</div>
<div class="class1 class2">B</div>
<div class="class1">C</div>
```

---

Ahora, si lo que quieres es seleccionar todos los elementos que tenga la clase1 y sólo la clase1 y ninguna más (ni la clase 2, ni la 3), utilizar `:not()` para eso puede no ser de mucha utilidad (porque no sabes los nombres de todas las clases y/o el selector sería largo y complejo).

En esos casos puedes usar un [selector de atributo (`[]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo) y seleccionar los elementos cuya clase sea exactamente clase1. Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo de cómo sería:

```js
const class1sinOtras = document.querySelectorAll("[class='class1']");
const class1con2 = document.querySelectorAll(".class1.class2");

console.log(class1sinOtras);
console.log(class1con2);
```

```html
<div class="class1">A</div>
<div class="class1 class2">B</div>
<div class="class1">C</div>
<div class="class1 class3">D</div>
<div class="class1">E</div>
```

Comment: Alvaro, y si quisiera los que son class1, pero ninguna otra clase atras? se puede? (si tuviera class1.class2 y class1.class3, hay algun tipo de comodin para esto?)

Comment: @gbianchi sí, se debería poder usando con selectores de atributo. Voy a probar y editar la respuesta

Comment: @gbianchi actualicé la respuesta para añadir esa posibilidad

Comment: Muchas gracias ! me ha servido mucho